# git on terminal: One folder- two git commits

Tags: git, github, terminal, bitbucket

I have just started an internship. I had two tasks about javascript. The first task i have finished and committed, the second one I just finished and am wondering how to commit it. Here is the structure: in the bitbucket repository there is one folder named javascript - for my tasks, but only one folder. In my home repository it is the same. I have one branch named javascript1 and have committed the first solution there. I have to commit my now second task but I am unsure of how. Do I create a second branch named javascript2 and put it there, or should I commit it to javascript1?

Also: the second task is a continued part of the first task.

Comment: What is the purpose of the **branch** javascript1?

Comment: You have to commit to the second branch if the first branch `javascript1` is merged to the parent branch. Otherwise, you can continue to commit in the first branch. It depends on the branching and architecture of your project.

Comment: I am not sure, just so I dont commit it to the original task maybe? They told me to add it.

Comment: Can you check you parent branch in bitbucket if your changes are there. If so, then create a new branch from the parent. Else, commit the changes of task2 in the first branch.

Comment: What do you mean by the first sentence?  The changes are not there because I have not committed. Sorry I am new to this